# Does grepping via helm support searching for multiple words in any order like other helm completions?

Tags: helm, search, grep

When searching multiple terms with Helm separated with spaces then Helm returns the results which mach the terms in any order. This is good.

Sometimes I try grep via helm. E.g. I use helm-recentf to select some files and run grep  on them. If I use a single term then it works fine. But if type two terms separated with space then I get no results.

My question is: does grep invoked via Helm support helm style out of order matching?

I'd like to determine if this feature is not supported or there is some problem with my config.

Answer (score 1):

The Helm's builtin Grep integration (such as `helm-recentf` and `helm-find-files`'s Grep action) does, when you enter "hello world", it will use `grep hello | grep world`.

Comment: Thanks. Then something is wrong at my side if it doesn't work for me.